# Android change colour of all views in custom component

Tags: android

My question is probably trivial, but the solutions I've found seem complex compared to what I need to do...

I want to set a custom overlay on a `RelativeLayout`. The overlay is composed of various parts that form an image. For the moment, I'm keeping the parts in a separate `<merge>` xml file for readability, and I use `<include>` to set them in the `RelativeLayout`. This works fine, but I'd like to change the overlay's colour at some point, but I don't want to have to parse through all the components to do that. Is there a simpler way to do this? Ideally, I'd want something like a custom view that contains the overlay views and that propagates its colour changes to its components.

something that I could use like this:

```
View overlay = (View)findViewById(R.id.custom_overlay);
overlayTop.setBackgroundResource(R.color.green_overlay);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So which one is the problem? The Overlay ViewGroup or the part about changing all of it's children's backgrounds?

Comment: The part about changing all the children's backgrounds. I'm just wondering what's the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

```
    ViewGroup overlay = (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.custom_overlay);
    for (int i = 0; i < overlay.getChildCount(); i++)
    {
        overlay.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.color.green_overlay);
    }
```

Comment: I have actually implemented something like this, but it is still an element by element change! It means that if I decide I want a colour transition on the overlay, I'll have to call it on every element, which is painful. And I'm not sure it would be done asynchronously.

Comment: Then you could try using a custom View that has a BroadcastReceiver in it and just listen for the set background event. I'm not sure that's the best of ideas, though. Ideally, views should be as dumb as possible and handling of broadcasts really belongs in the Controller (Activity). Even then, LocalBroadcastManager will iterate over all receivers it has registered, so you get pretty much the same problem.

Maybe your solution lies in making the iterative approach not painful?